# How much disk-space is needed to store a NULL value using postgresql DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, nullable

let's say I have a column on my table defined the following:

```
"MyColumn" smallint NULL
```

Storing a value like 0, 1 or something else should need 2 bytes (1). But how much space is needed if I set "MyColumn" to NULL? Will it need 0 bytes?

Are there some additional needed bytes for administration purpose or such things for every column/row?

(1) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Null columns are not stored. The row has a bitmap at the start and one bit per column that indicates which ones are null or non-null. The bitmap could be omitted if all columns are non-null in a row. So for any given row with one or more nulls, the size added to it would be that of the bitmap(N bits for an N-column table, rounded up).

More in depth discussion from the docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-page-layout.html#HEAPTUPLEHEADERDATA-TABLE)

Answer (score 88):

[Laramie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4229863/939860) is right about the bitmap and links to the right place in the manual. Yet, this is almost, but not quite correct:

> So for any given row with one or more nulls, the size added to it
> would be that of the bitmap(N bits for an N-column table, rounded up).

One has to factor in data alignment. The `HeapTupleHeader` (per row) occupies 23 bytes, actual column data always starts at a multiple of `MAXALIGN` (typically 8 bytes). That leaves one byte of padding that can be utilized by the null bitmap. In effect **null storage is absolutely free for tables up to 8 columns**.

After that, another `MAXALIGN` (typically 8) bytes are allocated for the next `MAXALIGN * 8` (typically 64) columns. Etc. Always for the total number of user columns (*all or nothing*). But only if there is at least one actual null value in the row.

Notably, dropped columns still listed in the system catalog `pg_attribute` (marked as dropped) also occupy one bit in the null bit map. Not even `VACUUM FULL` can get rid of this residue, only a dump/restore cycle does. (So beware of anti-patterns that would add and drop table columns routinely.)

I ran extensive tests to verify all of that. More details:

- [Does not using NULL in PostgreSQL still use a NULL bitmap in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008753/does-not-using-null-in-postgresql-still-use-a-null-bitmask-in-the-header/7383198#7383198)

Comment: Adding columns without a default value to large tables is usually a quick operation. Can it be slow when you cross the threshold between 8 and 9 columns (or 72 and 73 with `MAXALIGN = 8`)?

Comment: @PatrickBrinich-Langlois: Yes, that's a possible consequence of the mechanism. The physical table size also goes up more than one might expect in these cases. The effect is not necessarily linear as other factors like dead tuples are involved. The table does not grow at all if existing NULL bitmaps (per row) have space for another NULL bit, which is the common case.

Comment: Good Answer. As a side note: if Laramie is possibly not He but She or their, you could save three Bytes to get a gender neutral sentence _"Laramie is right about the bitmap and links to the right place in the manual."_

Comment: @StefanWuebbe: Better in any case. So why not.

Answer (score -1):

It should need 1 byte (0x00) however it's the structure of the table that makes up most of the space, adding this one value might change something (Like adding a row) which needs more space than the sum of the data in it.

**Edit:** Laramie seems to know more about null than me :)