# What is the cost of using NULL in database columns?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, postgresql, null

I use [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/null-values.html) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) often and plan on bringing more [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-comparison.html) into my workflow soon. With that in mind, what are the costs of using NULL in each database? I heard that MySQL adds an extra bit to each NULL column value to mark it as nullable.

Comment: Some DBMS treat null and empty as the same, as far as strings go (Sybase, MSSQL). For non-string types, a nullable type will always require more storage than a not-nullable type. This is because, as you've stated, you need at least a single bit to indicate whether or not the value is null or not. I suppose some DMBS may be able to compress data in some extent, but in a worst case, a nullable type will always consume more data than a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered separately for PostgreSQL:
[How much disk-space is needed to store a NULL value using postgresql DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229805/how-much-disk-space-is-needed-to-store-a-null-value-using-postgresql-db)

and for MySQL:
[NULL in MySQL (Performance & Storage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/null-in-mysql-performance-storage)

But to recap they both use bitmask fields to mark nulls.

Comment: Do they sill use those bitmask fields even if you don't use nulls?

Comment: what about SQLite?